# The ribbon will only display minimized

Tags: windows, delphi, for-loop, frameworks, ribbon

The ribbon displays fine in designer but is always minimized in runtime. Tried the following:
in OnShow of main form

rbnMain.Minimized:= False;
  rbnMain.Refresh;

also set Options|roAutoPreserveState to both true and false

Comment: Can you tell us which Ribbon, which Delphi, and a example?

Comment: We need a [mcve] to demonstrate. Create a bare-minimal application that demonstrates the issue, and then copy and paste the text .dfm and .pas files into your question. We can't debug code we can't see. The [mcve] should contain **only** the minimal code to demonstrate the problem - it should not contain empty procedures, commented out code blocks, or any code that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Must be a machine thing. The program executes perfectly on another computer.